# Android : Multiple Screen Support for All Devices

Tags: android

I'm working on my android project and didn't know that there was something called multiple screen support. I thought developing one kind of resolution would be the same on others. But i was wrong. Currently I've designed my app to work with resolution 1080*1920. But i want it to support all screen resolutions at least the below mentioned.

480*800,
1080*1920  (supports),
720*1280,
480*854,
480*960,
320*480,
1440*2560

So what can be done in this regard. I don't know what code to post here. Please guide me through this. Thank You

credits.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f6f6f6">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="The Team"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ff4a3b" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="PRAVEEN"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#010101"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="74dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="AKASH"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#010101"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="157dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="PRANOTI"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#010101"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="157dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="SONAL"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#010101"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="361dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="GUIDE"
        android:id="@+id/textView67"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ff4a3b" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView69"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView67"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"

        android:text="Prof. M.G.Huddar"
        android:id="@+id/textView89"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#010101"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView69"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView6" />

</RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did you read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html ?

Comment: @MorrisonChang sir please don't provide me articles, please give an example of it.

Comment: There are examples in the various samples both in the SDK in the samples directory and on github in https://github.com/googlesamples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=android It would be best to try you app on different resolutions. There is even a tutorial here from Google on it: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: I provided links as you provided no code or xml as to what you are doing and not stating what you expect to see but are not.

Comment: which code should i provide you, All the xmls are designed for 1080*1920 resolution. I can't change it to say 480*800 it would appear different.

Comment: What did you do before you get this error?

Comment: i created drawable-sw360dp,drawable-sw600dp,drawable-sw720dp and layout-sw360dp,layout-sw600dp,layout-sw720dp. Whatever was there in my normal layout folder and drawable folder I copied the same to each of the folders like layout to all 360,600,720 and drawable to 360,600,720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 5 folder.

Drawable-mdpi

Drawable-hdpi

Drawable-xhdpi

Drawable-xxhdpi

Drawable-xxxhdpi

or you can also use default folders

mipmap-mdpi

mipmap-hdpi

mipmap-xhdpi

mipmap-xxhdpi

mipmap-xxxhdpi

In these all folder you need to keep your images with ratio 1:1.5:2:3:4 .

all similar image have same name.

Now Other things done automatically, When someone use a Device with 360*480(hdpi). then it automatically fetch image from hdpi folder.

An Example for images.

If we take a image for

mdpi with 100dp*100dp.

then for hdpi :- 150dp*150dp

xhdpi:200dp*200dp

xxhdpi: 300dp*300dp

xxxhdpi: 400dp*400dp

Comment: ok i checked my res folder, It has already a folder called drawable and apart from that i created those 5 u mentioned. And yeah i also have mip-map n all. So what should i do? Should i delete the drawable folder and keep only those 5 drawable folders which u asked me to make

Comment: Tell me one thing, i have designed my app for 1080*1920 ok. I tested it and the components were arranged to the way i want it. Even if i use hdpi,ldpi,mdpi. The position of all the components in 480*800 gets changed. I just tested with ic_launcher being placed in various mipmap folders. What i see in 1080*1920 is entirely different from 480*800

Comment: No, You don't need to delete main drawable folder. Use it for other type of files, like selector etc.

Comment: Well dear. If you are using margin and padding like things to adjust your view. then it will work on only one device size.

Comment: but the position of components will vary right, what i have designed for 1080*1920 and the exact but shrinked i want it to support for 480*800

Comment: yaa i'm using that so wht should i do, in such case. I've navigation drawer with pre set padding, margin and even components have padding and margin

Comment: listen i have designed the app for 1080*1920 resolution, so it will work well with this resolution but is it possible that i manually rework with the components, like stretch them and make them look the way i want it for particular resolution.

Comment: well dear, except making issue for this small thing, Can you post one layout and particular images for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108067/discussion-between-akashdeep-singh-and-himanshu-shekher-jha).

Answer (score 1):

Supporting multiple devices is a headache. It used to be using hdpi, mdpi, xhdip, xxhdip to specify different device sizes. Now, it's using sw320dp, sw360dp, sw600dp, etc. Where **sw** stands for **smallest width**, **dp** stands for **Density-independent Pixels**. So,

If you create a layout file **activity_main.xml** in the **res/layout-sw360dp** folder, it will be used for devices with screen width >= 360dp. Now, if you create another file with the same name **activity_main.xml** but in a folder **res/layout-sw600dp**, then this file will be used for devices with screen width >= 600dp.

This applies for drawable, dimen and value files as well.

res/drawable-sw360dp for devices with screen width >= 360dp

res/drawable-sw600dp for devices with screen width >= 600dp

res/drawable-sw720dp for devices with screen width >= 720dp

etc.

You get the idea...

I wrote a [post](http://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-device-and-layout-mapping/) about this not while ago about this. [Official Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers). [Device Size Metrics](https://design.google.com/devices/)

Comment: i have posted the logcat have alook

Answer (score 0):

Android devices have multiple densities classified as ldpi (low), mdpi (medium), hdpi(high) and xhdpi(extra-high). Generally, the bigger the resolution of a device is, the higher it's density gets. So low-resolution devices have a ldpi, medium-res devices have mdpi and so on. To implement this, go to your resources folder and create some new folders called drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi and place your images inside them. The images in the drawable-ldpi should have lower resolutions, and will be automatically used on devices that have low resolution (there's no need for you to programatically implement this). The images inside drawable-mdpi should have a bigger resolution than the ldpi ones, and so on. Like this you can make sure every device gets it's right image. You can place an image in all of these folders without renaming it. For example you can place a file called image.png in all of those folders, and when accessing it through R.id.image, the system will automatically choose in which folder it'll look for it. Hope this helps!

Comment: tell me one thing say for example i have one image "x.jpg" how do i convert it to ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi

Comment: Your question doesn't seem clear enough, do you want to resize your images accordingly to the resolutions or do you want all of the layouts and views to scale to different screens, maintaining the same aspect?

Comment: resizing images to each resolution is not practical. I have developed my app using 1080*1920 as i had no clue how my app will look on other resolutions but when i got to know about this, I thought how my app will work on every resolution

Comment: You must create different versions of the image, in which you change resolutions. ldpi is 75% of mdpi, hdpi is 150% of mdpi, and xhdpi is 200% of mdpi. So if your current device screen is 1080x1900, your images are currently in xhdpi resolutions. Halve their resolution to get to mdpi, and then create other versions for the other ones.

Comment: is there any website or any software that creates different versions of image like ldpi,hdpi,mdpi,xdpi,xxdpi